# Is there a way to call a django model function from a template inside an javascript function?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am trying to trigger my note.send function (from a  method) whenever I call a javascript function.

Here is my Javascript code.

```
function send_mail(){
            {{ note.send }}
            }
```

I then call the function `send_mail()` whenever an specific action happens on the website, however the django template function is called each time I reload the website even if I don't call the javascript function at all. Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: If you javascript is inside a template you can do it. Or, you can use the template engine to build javascript.. but with a non-static url to it.. Or you can use something like handlebars.js and use ajax to get some json from django...